# Regular expression to fetch the value from a given string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string:

```
a=<record><FPR_AGENT_CODE>990042833</FPR_AGENT_CODE><FPR_AGENT_LABELCODE>CIF Code :</FPR_AGENT_LABELCODE><FPR_AGENT_LABELNAME>CIF Name :</FPR_AGENT_LABELNAME>
```

I need to get the value from:

```
<FPR_AGENT_CODE>990042833</FPR_AGENT_CODE>
```

to

```
"FPR_AGENT_CODE 990042833 FPR_AGENT_CODE"
```

How can I write the regular expression for this? I tried using the one given below, but it's not working.

```
puts a[/<.*>.*<\/.*>/]
```

Comment: No, I need the value within angle brackets like 'FPR_AGENT_CODE' and value '990042833'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scan` with the following regex:

```
/<([^>]+)>(\d+)<\/\1>/
```

[Sample code](http://ideone.com/J9YrPo):

```
a="<record><FPR_AGENT_CODE>990042833</FPR_AGENT_CODE><FPR_AGENT_LABELCODE>CIF Code :</FPR_AGENT_LABELCODE><FPR_AGENT_LABELNAME>CIF Name :</FPR_AGENT_LABELNAME><FPR_AGENT_NAME>Mr Kamal Kishore</FPR_AGENT_NAME><FPR_BANK_BRANCH_NAME>STATE BANK OF INDIA KHOUR</FPR_BANK_BRANCH_NAME><FPR_BRANCH_ADDRESS>"
puts a.scan(/<([^>]+)>(\d+)<\/\1>/)
```

Output:

```
FPR_AGENT_CODE
990042833
```

The regex `<([^>]+)>(\d+)<\/\1>` searches for a string in angle brackets (capturing the text into group 1), then a sequence of 1 or more digits (`\d+`), and then the closing tag.

If you need to get multiple values, you can use:

```
puts a.scan(/<([^>]+\b)[^<>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/)
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/Tuttfp), output:

```
FPR_AGENT_CODE
990042833
FPR_AGENT_LABELCODE
CIF Code :
FPR_AGENT_LABELNAME
CIF Name :
FPR_AGENT_NAME
Mr Kamal Kishore
FPR_BANK_BRANCH_NAME
STATE BANK OF INDIA KHOUR
```

For multiline input, either use `m` option, or replace `(.*?)` with `([^<]*)`.

```
puts a.scan(/<([^>]+\b)[^<>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/m)
```

Or

```
puts a.scan(/<([^>]+\b)[^<>]*>([^<]*)<\/\1>/)
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/CvlFXB)

Comment: No no, not only for 'FPR_AGENT_CODE' for all the tags, <></> and the value is not only for numbers, anything needs to be displayed.

Comment: I did  it now, Thanks.

Comment: hi, If the closing brackets comes in next line, then it's missing it, What can I do to rectify this?

     <name>fdfdjfd
     </name>

This case it's missing."</name>" is coming in next line.

Comment: Use `m` option, or replace `(.*?)` with `([^<]*)`. Please choose one that suits you best. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/CvlFXB).

Comment: hi When I give this "<FPR_AGENT_LBELCODE>CIF Code :</FPR_AGENT_LABELCODE>" , the code is not displaying the result, what might be reason?

a="<FPR_AGENT_LBELCODE>CIF Code :</FPR_AGENT_LABELCODE>"

a.scan(/<([^>]+\b)[^<>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/m).each do |i,j|
 puts i 
end
 I am running this code, but it's not giving any results, Is it working for you?

Comment: Your opening tag is *FPR_AGENT_L**B**ELCODE*, and the closing one is *FPR_AGENT_L**AB**ELCODE*. Try `puts a.scan(/<([^>]+\b)[^<>]*>([^<]*)<\/[^>]+>/)`. However, this regex won't check for paired tags.

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't noticed that, yes it's fine now, and your newly given works fine too.